# Identify common values for a group

Tags: python

I use datasets that are often CSV flats files that are the result of a variety of other source tables.

I import them using pandas read_csv.

For example. I get a table like this :

| ID | Amount | Client | Company | Company Long Name | ID2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 12 | ClientA | CompanyA | The Company A | AA123 |
| 1 | 2 | ClientA | CompanyA | The Company A | AA2339 |
| 2 | 32 | ClientB | CompanyA | The Company A | AA3833 |
| 3 | 1 | ClientB | CompanyB | The Company B | BB3933 |

Now I suppose there is a "Company" table somewhere. And I would like to find a way to find columns that are very likely to be from this company table.

So I want to ask with python if working with the columns `Company` there are any "good candidates" for a potential `Company Table`

In my example, `Company Long Name` is a good candidate because if I group by `Company` and count how many unique values I have for the column `Company Long Name`, the answer is 1.

Also, what I wish to find is whether part of a column would be a good match as well. In my example, the first two characters of `ID2` are a good fit.

Ideally, I would like a just provide a columns and the code check everyother columns (I have hundreds of them) and suggest good candidates with maybe some idea of a matching score. Like 99% meaning that there may be a occurence where I have more than 1 distinct value for this company ID.

Comment: Welcome! Sorry, but what you ask isn't our thing around here. Please review [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a specific question about your implementation. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation, and is not a way to have research, design or coding work done for you.

Comment: I'm a data science newb, but I wonder if you could use naive bayesian classifiers for this, with maybe some extra sauce for the prefix matching.

Comment: If you are looking for a more statistical approach like naive bayes it might be worth asking instead on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/). I think @CryptoFool's comment is that usually it's preferred if people at least make an attempt and post what they've tried before asking a question. It helps narrow down the problem and clarify exactly how answerers can help. Interesting question, though...